# StackExchange.Redis Blocking pop design

Tags: c#, stackexchange.redis

So we had an existing Helper library that used ServiceStack.Redis and currently trying to swap it with StackExchange.Redis. We were using BlockingPop (BLPOP) but since StackExchange.Redis doesn't support it. we implemented it as follows

```
public static void Push(string Qname, string val)
{
    IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();
    db.ListLeftPush(Qname, val);
    ISubscriber sub = redis.GetSubscriber();
    sub.Publish(Qname + "_msg", "1");
}
```

and Pop with blocking option as follows:

```
    public static string Pop(string Qname, 
    bool block_until_available = false,int timeout_secs=0)
{   
    IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();            
    var popped = db.ListRightPop(Qname);
    if (popped.IsNull)
    {
        if (block_until_available == false)
            return null;
    }
    else
        return popped;

    //wait for an item to be pushed in.
    ISubscriber sub = redis.GetSubscriber();
    AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    string obj = null;
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        sub.Subscribe(Qname + "_msg", (channel, message) =>
        {
            popped = db.ListRightPop(Qname);
            if (!popped.IsNull)
            {
                obj = popped;
                sub.Unsubscribe(Qname + "_msg");
                autoEvent.Set();
            }
        });
    });
    if (timeout_secs > 0)
        autoEvent.WaitOne(timeout_secs * 1000);
    else
        autoEvent.WaitOne();
    return obj;
}
```

Do you all see any obvious issue with this approach.

Also, I quickly ran into following error. I have increased the syncTimeout. hopefully that will fix it?

```
System.TimeoutException: Timeout performing RPOP DL_PROD, 
inst: 0, mgr: ProcessReadQueue, err: never, queue: 0, qu: 0, qs: 0, qc: 0, 
wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 0, ar: 1, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=8,Max=1000), 
WORKER: (Busy=2,Free=32765,Min=8,Max=32767), 
clientName: CD147RE1 at 
StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T]
(Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server)
```

Comment: I don't know why this is downvoted - the question is fair

Comment: I have run into multiple issue with this solution. Please use this solution with extreme caution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no specific reason RPOP should timeout here, unless it is bandwidth related (huge payloads). That error looks unrelated to the question IMO. The approach is a big ugly but ... well, it might work. There's no need to use Task.Run here, though. One problem in the approach is that it won't work correctly concurrently, I think. It seems to unsubscribe all delegates for that channel / connection, rather than just the one. Self-unsubscribing is possible, but frankly I wonder if it is easier to just have a single auto-reset-event and a single subscription, and if a message unlocks the gate while you're waiting: *great*.

---

The general pattern of self-unsubscribing delegates is essentially:

```
YourDelegateType handler = null;
handler = (args) => {
    DoTheThing();
    UnSubscribe(handler);
};
Subscribe(handler);
```

This uses the joy of lexical captured variables to provide access to the delegate instance *inside* the delegate, which means the delegate can pass *itself* to an unsubscribe method. The pattern shown above should work for all delegate-based callback scenarios - including regulate events and things like SE.Redis pub/sub handlers.

Comment: No, the payloads are small. Redis is barely utilized. only thing I could think of is network. Good point about unsubscribing and single subscription idea. will look into that.

Comment: also how do I self unsubscribe?

Comment: @coderguy123 that is more complex; will show in an edit

Comment: Another issue I am running into though, sometimes (very rare) the signal to channel from "Push" operation is lost, so consumer never pops it. the message is still in the queue. Do you think I need to add a time delay between leftpush and publish? these are not in Fireandforget mode, so I thought should be sync and shouldn't matter?

Comment: @coderguy123 hard to know without a repro, but this is usually a timing problem (in particular between the pub/sub vs command connections) - hence why I suspect a single subscription would be more stable (as it removes the timing issues). Either way: putting a timeout / retry would probably be a good idea.

Comment: I will add some time delay and test out again. I wrote a simple producer consumer app to test this out. I took out that Task.Run as you pointed out. I tested with 1 producer and 1 consumer and that missing signal issue happened even when the producer waited for consumer to finish before sending another job - in other words - don't think it is threading/multiple subscription issue. The test ran fine for 18 hrs then failed.